# A way out without any toolkit to save an svg container as a .svg file?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using d3.js and plotting a dynamic graph which is interactive in nature. Everything is being saved in an svg container and now I want to save that container as .svg or .png file which can be edited in a software like corelDraw or something. I have tried looking at many things online by googling this of course but couldn't understand anything. Any help in a direction will be appreciated.
Thank you
Update - @Jaco, I put a sample code here as you suggested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
</style>
<body>
<script src="d3.js"></script>//I'm using the d3 library source code locally
<script>//code here which reads a json file (local) and shows a graph when opened in browser, part of it is here where I declare svg and keep appending the stuff to it for drawing.
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);
//here I append circles to the svg and texts (labels) and links
//some functions are declare to control the behaviour
//nodes are appended as circles (one class)
</script> //I use the id as svg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below a basic example allowing to save SVG. You will also need to handle styles if you have added those.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-container"></div>
<button id="svg-save" type="button">Save</button>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var width = 100;
    var height = 100;
    var svg = d3.select("#svg-container").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var circle = svg.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 30)
      .attr("cy", 30)
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("fill","red")
  });
  
  $('#svg-save').click(function() {
  var svg = document.getElementById('svg-container');
  //you need to clone your SVG otherwise it will disappear after saving
  var clone = svg.cloneNode(true);
  var svgDocType = document.implementation.createDocumentType('svg', "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN", "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd");
  var svgDoc = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg', svgDocType);

  svgDoc.replaceChild(clone, svgDoc.documentElement);
  var svgData = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svgDoc);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData.replace(/></g, '>\n\r<'));
  a.download = 'downloaded.svg';
  a.innerHTML = 'download the svg file';

  //Hack alert: create a temporary link to download the svg
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer And I get a bit of it, but how do I get this to work exactly. As in, where do I specify my html file coded using javascript in here or does this code snippet go into my code?

Comment: This example grabs the content of the svg container with `id` equal to `svg-container` and re-formats it as a standalone SVG file. It would have been useful if you had posted a simplified version of your code, you probably would have gotten less downvotes.

Comment: Hey @Jaco, I apologize and have edited and pasted a sample code here. Thank you

Comment: I have adapted the code to use d3, the `$(document).ready` function now draws the circle using d3 and the `$('#svg-save').click` function saves it. Please note I am place the SVG inside a div, it makes it easier just to grab the SVG content and nothing else.

Comment: Ok @Jaco, I think I somewhat got it. I'll try again now and contact you further. Thanks for all the help